# Cannot access object inside of array (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, object

I have created a class as such:

```
 class Task {
        var name:String
        var description:String
        var date:NSDate
        var taskCompleted:Bool

        init(name:String, description:String,date:NSDate, taskCompleted:Bool){
            self.name = name
            self.description = description
            self.date = date
            self.taskCompleted = taskCompleted
        }
    }
```

I then create a new object like so:

```
let newTask:AnyObject = Task(name: taskName.text!, description: descriptionInput.text, date: datePicker.date, taskCompleted: false)
```

Later on I add the object to an array:

```
var tasks = [AnyObject]()
tasks.append(newTask)
```

However, when I try to access the object again like so I get an error:

```
print(tasks[0].name)
```

**ERROR: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Comment: Why AnyObject? Just use Task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is of type `[AnyObject]`. If you want to avoid using as keyword, you should make it of type `[Task]` because `AnyObject` doesn't necesseraly have a `name` property. This is why it yells found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Try this :

```
let newTask:Task = Task(name: taskName.text!, description: descriptionInput.text, date: datePicker.date, taskCompleted: false)

var tasks = [Task]()
tasks.append(newTask)

print(tasks[0].name)
```

Like Lindsey said, you can use the `as` keyword if you want to have different types of objects in it but I don't think that is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

In your current code `tasks[0]` is of type `AnyObject` which does not have a "name" property. Try changing:

```
print(tasks[0].name)
```

to

```
print((tasks[0] as! Task).name)
```

in order to change `tasks[0]` from `AnyObject` to `Task`.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

Currently when you access a task from your array you get back an `AnyObject` which knows nothing about your `name` attribute.

You can do one of two things depending on what you are trying to accomplish

1. You can set your array to be of type `[Task]` not `AnyObject`.
2. Cast the `AnyObject` to `Task` when retrieving it from array. `(task[0] as! Task).name`

Comment: Thanks for the input!